# How to retrieve data from custom table in database?

Tags: 7, database

I created a custom table in my modules .install file and I am asking for some form input in a custom made configuration file. I am unable to retrieve that data and print it out in a custom callback page that i created for testing. I'm not quite sure what i am doing wrong.

```
<?php
/* mymodule.install */
function mymodule_schema(){
  $schema['mymodule'] = array(
    'description' => 'Table for testing',
    'fields' => array(
      'pmid' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'field_one' => array(
        'description' => 'Field 1',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => ''
      ),
      'primary key' => array('pmid'),
      'unique keys' => array(
        'pmid' => array('pmid'),
      ),
     ),
   );

/* mymodule.module */
function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  db_insert('mymodule')
  ->fields(array(
    'field_one' => $form_state['values']['field_one'],
    'pmid' => 1,
  ))->execute();
}

function mymodule_print_table(){
$result = db_select('mymodule', 'mm')
       ->fields('field_one') 
       ->execute()
       ->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
}
```

This prints an empty array for me.

EDIT:

I incorrectly assumed form_submit was a hook and didn't add it to my form.

```
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state){
$form['field_one'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Field One'),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#description' => t('Field One Test'),
    '#required' => true,
  );
//This was missing
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_submit';

return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Comment: Are you facing problem in save the record or fetch the record?

Comment: the real problem was saving the record, i though fetching was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fields` method takes a table name/alias as its first arg, and an array of field names as its second:

```
$result = db_select('mymodule', 'mm')
   ->fields('mm', ['field_one']) 
   ->execute()
   ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I made the changes but it still prints an empty array. Checking on PHPmyadmin shows the tables fields as empty. If I manually add entries to the table fields in PHPmyadmin then it does print correctly. My guess is that `mymodule_form_submit` function is not being called.

Comment: @blu I have corrected the quotes on Clive's answer. If you copy pasted, try again now.